# Were the Jail Scaglietti clones removed from all of The Numbers?

Tags: nanoha

At the end of Magical Girl Lyrical StrikerS, it's revealed that all of [The Numbers](http://nanoha.wikia.com/wiki/Number) had a clone of [Jail Scaglietti](http://nanoha.wikia.com/wiki/Jail_Scaglietti) in their wombs, so that in the event of his capture or death, as long as one of The Numbers escaped, his clone would be born with all his memories and knowledge, effectively allowing him to reborn.

A number of The Numbers were separated and imprisoned in different locations, while a group (who probably could be released and live normal lives like Subaru and Ginga) were in a separate facility near Ground Forces H.Q.

Were all the Jail Scaglietti clones removed from the wombs of The Numbers? Or only those who would be released, since the others would be imprisoned indefinitely?

Answer (score 1):

The clones are never mentioned again in the series. One possible explanation is that they were supposed to trigger in case of Jail Scaglietti's death; but he is still alive, in a maximum security orbital prison.

Comment: I think they do get some mention.  I think they appear in sound stages, and if I remember correctly the ones that chose to try to rehabilitate have appeared in Vivid (possibly Force?).  I can't recall specific ones, though, so maybe I'm mistaken.  I don't think any of those mention the clones, regardless.  The "trigger only on death" does seem to be the prevalent fan theory, from what a cursory search would reveal.

Comment: To clarify, the _Numbers_ certainly appear (everyone but Quattro in SSX, the ones who chose rehabilitation in Vivid and Force), but the _clones of Jail_ are never mentioned. The possibilities would seem to be: 1) continued dormancy due to Jail not being dead, 2) abortions -- which are not as morally fraught in Japanese culture as in Western/Christian culture, or 3) Jail was bluffing.  There's absolutely no evidence for any of these, so you pays your money and you takes your choice.

Comment: Scaglietti tells Fate after his capture that the clones are due to be born in a month's time, which contradicts the idea that they'll only be born if the real Scaglietti dies.